# PHP While Loop to Display Results in Google Charts

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, google-visualization

I have a PHP While loop:

```
$workgroups = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a.TASK_ID, a.DELETE_WEEK, SUM(a.MON_BILL+a.TUE_BILL+a.WED_BILL+a.THU_BILL+a.FRI_BILL) AS hours, b.ID, b.TITLE, b.GROUP_ID, c.ID, c.NAME, d.VALUE_ID, reverse(reverse(d.VALUE) + 0) AS companyid, e.VALUE_ID, e.UF_CRM_1384938829 AS hourrate, f.ID, f.TITLE as companyname FROM b_report_week a INNER JOIN b_tasks b ON a.TASK_ID = b.ID INNER JOIN b_sonet_group c ON b.GROUP_ID = c.ID INNER JOIN b_utm_tasks_task d ON a.TASK_ID = d.VALUE_ID INNER JOIN b_uts_crm_company e ON reverse(reverse(d.VALUE) + 0) = e.VALUE_ID INNER JOIN b_crm_company f ON reverse(reverse(d.VALUE) + 0) = f.ID WHERE a.DELETE_WEEK = 0 GROUP BY a.TASK_ID");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($workgroups))
{
$taskTitle = $row['TITLE'];
$taskTotalHours = $row['hours'];
$companyName = $row['companyname'];
$companyRate = number_format($row['hourrate'] / 7.50,2);
$valueTotal = number_format($row['hours'] * number_format($row['hourrate'] / 7.50,2),2);
}
```

This produces the correct results in a table if I were to draw a table inside the loop (Displays about 8 rows with the 5 columns identified above).  What I am wanting is to display the $companyname down the Y axis and the $valueTotal across the x axis.  I rather new to Google graphs but I've tried the following (to no joy):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Company', 'Sales'],

<I INSERTED THE ABOVE PHP CODE WITH CONNECTION DETAILS HERE WITH A CLOSING ?>>

['<?php echo $companyName; ?>',  <?php echo $valueTotal; ?>],

<?php } ?> <!-- Ends the While Loop -->

['Last Row', 0]

]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      vAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>

<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 800px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use orientation : 'vertical', parameter in options array

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Company', 'Sales'],
 <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {?>
 ['<?php echo $row['company']?>',  <?php echo $row['valueTotal']?>],
 <?php } ?>
]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      orientation : 'vertical',
      vAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This hasn't changed anything.  The graph isn't showing up still.

Comment: try this


var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['company', 'Sales'], 
  <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {?>
              
          ['<?php echo $row['company']?>',  <?php echo $row['valueTotal']?>],
    <?php } ?>
        ]);


var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
    orientation : 'vertical',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };

Comment: No this doesn't do anything either.  It's pretty similar to what I already have.

Comment: oh remove the number_format function and use round  function

change 

$companyRate = number_format($row['hourrate'] / 7.50,2);
$valueTotal = number_format($row['hours'] * number_format($row['hourrate'] / 7.50,2),2);

to

$companyRate = round($row['hourrate'] / 7.50,2);
$valueTotal = round($row['hours'] * number_format($row['hourrate'] / 7.50,2),2);

Comment: I've just removed the <?php echo $row['company']?> and put test in there.  This now shows the graph with the correct values along the X axis but test in place of where it should be company name on the Y axis.  Which highlights its the company name section which is the issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: use parameter orientation : 'vertical', in options array

Comment: I've added: orientation : 'vertical', under options array

Answer (score 0):

Data should be numeric, `number_format` returns `string`. Use `round` as suggested above or cast to appropriate type with `(float)` or `(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<?php
    $workgroups = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a.TASK_ID, a.DELETE_WEEK, SUM(a.MON_BILL+a.TUE_BILL+a.WED_BILL+a.THU_BILL+a.FRI_BILL) AS hours, b.ID, b.TITLE, b.GROUP_ID, c.ID, c.NAME, d.VALUE_ID, reverse(reverse(d.VALUE) + 0) AS companyid, e.VALUE_ID, e.UF_CRM_1384938829 AS hourrate, f.ID, f.TITLE as companyname FROM b_report_week a INNER JOIN b_tasks b ON a.TASK_ID = b.ID INNER JOIN b_sonet_group c ON b.GROUP_ID = c.ID INNER JOIN b_utm_tasks_task d ON a.TASK_ID = d.VALUE_ID INNER JOIN b_uts_crm_company e ON reverse(reverse(d.VALUE) + 0) = e.VALUE_ID INNER JOIN b_crm_company f ON reverse(reverse(d.VALUE) + 0) = f.ID WHERE a.DELETE_WEEK = 0 GROUP BY a.TASK_ID");
    $data = array(array('Company', 'Sales'));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($workgroups)) {
        $taskTitle = $row['TITLE'];
        $taskTotalHours = $row['hours'];
        $companyName = $row['companyname'];
        $companyRate = number_format($row['hourrate'] / 7.50,2);
        $valueTotal = number_format($row['hours'] * number_format($row['hourrate'] / 7.50,2),2);
        $data[] = array($companyName, $valueTotal);
    }
    $data[] = array('Last Row', 0);
?>
```

In javascript:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>);
```